# GSON Deserialize object with member ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, json, list, gson, deserialization

I've seen a lot of similar questions. I haven't been able to find any that fit my exact issue. In all of the examples I've found the List is of an object type defined in the parent class, whereas I just have a list of Strings. I've tried using a simple array String[], and I've seen examples with overloading deserializers, and getting the TypeToken but I can't tie it together to make this work. My list is always empty (or null if I don't initialize it when I define the list). What am I missing here, it feels like I'm trying to do something very simple but everything I find on it looks overly complex.

This is my class:

```
public class MondoConfig {
private String merchantURL;
public ArrayList<String> targets = new ArrayList<String>();


public MondoConfig () {}

public String getMerchantURL() {
    return this.merchantURL;
}

public void setMerchantURL(String url) {
    this.merchantURL = url;
}

public ArrayList<String> getTargets() {
    return this.targets;
}

public void setTargets(ArrayList<String> t) {
    this.targets = t;


}
}
```

This is my json:

```
{
"merchantURL":"https://example.com/collections/posters",
"targets":[
"testing",
"another",
"one more"
]
}
```

And my code to deserialize:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\mondo_config.json"));
MondoConfig config = gson.fromJson(br, MondoConfig.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing a few problems in your code, but I was able to get it to work without any issues.

```
package org.nuttz.gsonTest;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MondoConfig {
   private String merchantURL;
   public ArrayList<String> targets = new ArrayList<String>();

   MondoConfig () {}

   public String getMerchantURL() {
      return this.merchantURL;
   }

   public void setMerchantURL(String url) {
      this.merchantURL = url;
   }

   public ArrayList<String> getTargets() {
      return this.targets;
   }

   public void setTargets(ArrayList<String> t) {
      this.targets = t;
   }
}
```

The setMerchantURL() function in your original code wasn't quite right, so I fixed it. Then I used this code to test it:

```
package org.nuttz.gsonTest;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.*;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
       Gson gson = new Gson();
       try {
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/jim/mondoconfig.json"));
          MondoConfig config = gson.fromJson(br, MondoConfig.class);
          System.out.println("Contents of config:");
          System.out.println(config.getMerchantURL());
          List<String> targets = config.targets;
          for (String t : targets) {
             System.out.println(t);
          }
       }
       catch (Exception x) {
          x.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

And got the following results:

```
Contents of config:
https://example.com/collections/posters
testing
another
one more
```

This is using the 2.8.2 version of GSON. In other words, you're on the right track, you've just need to fix the MondoConfig class.

Comment: This problem with setMerchantURL was a problem when i copy pasted to stackoverflow. So now I'm even more confused as to why my code is not working

Comment: If you copy my code directly, does it work? Are you actually opening the file you think you are?

Comment: I have not copied pasted your code exactly. I will try that when I get home tonight. I know I am opening the right file because the other members of the class are being populated correctly.

Comment: Oh goddamn it. I had saved the json file in another location on the computer then copy/pasted it to c:/location. That was before I had added the targets array. I was editing the file in the original location which is why all the rest of the data was correct. Thanks for all your help and especially asking what is essentially the "is it plugged in?" support question.